# What are the (possible) future plans for Ubuntu-izing 3rd party software (please read details)?

Tags: package-management, software-sources

I know the title is confusing, because honestly it is hard to find the correct title. What I am asking is basically, in light of unity, ubuntu-one and other such projects, is Canonical/The Ubuntu Development team (correct me about the proper title :P) planning on more original software?

For instance, Ubuntu is quickly becoming a strong ecosystem of it's own, but has to rely on a lot 3rd party software in various areas, which is fine (I love that), but sometimes this software has major shortcomings that Ubuntu inherits. Programs like Skype, (sorry I can find any other off hand examples) miss out in major areas, such as proper desktop integration. If Ubuntu has it's own client side software, then it could be better integrated and more appealing.

Another example is backup. Ubuntu One is great for that, and getting better, but for example, Deja Dup is not installed be default, and even if it was, misses some integration features on Ubuntu (and will in the future as the ecosystem becomes more unique). This could be used as the basis for built in backup software of course, just with better integration with Ubuntu.

In a nutshell then,

- Is there some kind of roadmap/blueprint governing the direction Ubuntu will take in the future regarding such software?
- How is Canonical planning to engage the community in the process of developing Ubuntu's wider software identity?

(Sorry if my question seems confusing/like_a_rant/mixed_up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that your best bet for a heads up on this stuff is to follow the Ayatana mailing list here :
https://lists.launchpad.net/ayatana/

However that list focusses mostly on design, rather than straight software development roadmap.

Given how UbuntuOne and UbuntuFont was developed offline then introduced into betas with little to no prior announcement, I'm guessing that some things are still decided behind closed doors at the Canonical offices (they are a company out to make money after all and their developers are paid to do a job).

Comment: Well put answer :)! I agree that the developers need to do some things in private, so maybe it's best kept as is in some ways ^^. Thanks! (put my thinking in the right gear)

Comment: The Ayatana list is a real eye-opener really.  They're a smart bunch of cookies, even if they overthink some stuff a little...